# Find rows that contain all words in any order

Tags: sql, sql-server

My application is built in vb.net with SQL Server Compact as the database so I'm unable to use a full-text index.

Here's my data...

`MainTable` field1

1. A B C
2. B G C
3. X Y Z
4. C P B

Search term = B C

**Expected Results** = any combination of the search term = Rows 1, 2, 4

Here's what I'm currently doing...

I'm permuting the search term `B C` into an array containing `%B%C%` and `%C%B%` and inserting those values into field1 of `tempTable`.

So my SQL looks like this:

`SELECT * FROM MainTable INNER JOIN tempTable ON MainTable.field1 LIKE tempTable.field1`

In this simple example, it does return the expected results correctly. However, my search term can contain more values. For example 6 search terms `B C D E F G` when permuted has 720 different values and as more search terms are used, the permutations grow exponentially...which is not good.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The only way I can figure out is to split the data from spaces into rows, only include rows (=words) in the list, and calculate distinct values, which should then be the number of words you're looking for. Probably horribly slow for any big data sets :)

Comment: It doesn't matter how many permutations exist provided you convert search string (`A B C D E F`) into a single-column table (`@termTable`). (`select distinct m.* from maintable m inner join @termTable t on m.field1 like '%'+t.term+'%'`) Another approach. If CLR assembly is possible it may give you custom ranking.

Comment: This `select distinct m.* from maintable m inner join @termTable t on m.field1 like '%'+t.term+'%'` doesn't work because each of the search terms in `A B C D E F` can be in any order in the data. It could be `B A F E D C`, it could be `A X Y Z B C D E F`, etc and I want all of those results returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will work for your example above:

```
Select * from table where field1 like '%[BC]%'
```

But it will also return strings that contain ONLY "B" or "C".  Do you need both characters in any order or one or more?

**EDIT:**  Then the following would work:

```
Select * from test_data where col1 LIKE '%Apple%' and col1 like '%Dog%'
```

See the demo here:  http://rextester.com/edit/LNDQ49764

Comment: results must contain both in any order

Comment: My example above is very simple but to be clearer, if I'm searching for `Apple Dog` and the data had 4 rows containing the following: `Apple Dog`, `Dog Apple`, `Apple Cat Dog`, `Dog House Car Apple`...then I want all of these 4 rows returned.

Comment: Interesting...I'll look into that and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: I tested your solution and it does work. I don't know why that didn't occur to me. I guess I was thinking that it would treat each condition separately, but instead it takes it all together because of the `AND`...which makes sense. Thanks for the help.